# Fastest way to format a String using concatenation and manipulation

Tags: java, concatenation

```
String temp = "";

temp = String.format("%02d", ""+hour)+":"+String.format("%02d", ""+min)+":"+String.format("%02d", ""+sec);
```

Is this the fastest way to format the numbers with concatenation to specify leading zeroes, or is there another way?

I have to display the String in the format 00:00:00. The hour, min, and sec are int variables which start from 0 and are put into the Thread which counts the time elapsed and displays this time accordingly. Is this the correct way, or is there any better way?

Comment: +1 for apologies however it wasn't necessary :) [Pardon my bracket conversation : Bapu aavu to chaila rake alma sorry hu kaiye lol ;)]

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try this. I assume that hour, min and sec are ints.

```
String temp = "";
temp = String.format("%02d:%02d:%02d", hour, min, sec);
```